# When starting appium server programmatically using java in eclipse taking too much time

Tags: java, appium-android

I'm using the following code to start the Appium server:

```
AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
appiumService.start();
```

**The problem:**

It's taking approx 3 mins to start the server.

I am using appium 1.8.0-beta5

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i am starting appium server using my java code but when i run the code it is taking around 3 mins to start the appium server

Comment: Please read up on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question according to standarts

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for starting appium server programmatically which will take less than 3 minutes :

```
// start appium server
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"appium -a 0.0.0.0 -p 4723\"");
                //get address of appium server
                URL u=new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub");
                //provide device and app info
                DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
                dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,"");
                dc.setCapability("deviceName","yh8uujujfhuh");
                dc.setCapability("platformName","android");
                dc.setCapability("platformVersion","6.0");
                dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.google.android.apps.maps");
                dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
                //create driver object to launch app in device
                AndroidDriver driver;
                while(2>1) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        driver=new AndroidDriver(u,dc);
                        break;//terminate from loop
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

AppiumDriverLocalService appiumService = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
appiumService.start();

will work fast if appium version is 1.8.0 not 1.8.0-beta5